# '0' before a number in sum_of_digits gives wrong answer

Tags: python-2.7

this is the function that returns sum of digits of a given no.
ex: 345 gives 12 (3+4+5)

```
def digit_sum(n):
  s=0
  while(n>0):
    r=n%10
    n=n/10
    s=s+r
  return s
print digit_sum(0123)
```

output: **11** instead of 6

Comment: Prefix `0` means you interpret a number as an octal number. Since it is confusing, this feature has been removed in Python-3.x

Comment: Evil downvote for a well written question with documented and expected output. This is truly bewildering when you first encounter this.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to Python 3, `0123` is an *octal* literal as it starts with a leading `0`.

(Its decimal value is 83, and those digits sum to 11.)

Comment: Blame the C geeks from the 1970s. **Why did python continue with this?**. At the very least, they should have gone for `0o` for Octal.

Comment: this has been fixed in python3. octal needs to be written as `0o123`. `0123` is a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: That's wonderful. And they adopted my favourite notation! Python is amazing!